# Spectral Intensity of complex signal

Tags: electromagnetism, fourier-transform, signal-processing, complex-analysis

I'm simulating an electromagnetic wave that has a real and imaginary part. Something like:

$$  E(x,t) = A(x,t) e^{-i(\omega t - k x)} $$

Where $A(x,t)$ is some complex amplitude. Then taking the physical intensity:

$$ I(x,t) \propto |E(x,t)|^2 = A(x,t)\cdot A(x,t)^* = |A(x,t)|^2 $$

Now then if I take the FFT of a bunch of points in space and time I expect the spectral intensity to be something like:

$$ \tilde{I}(k,\omega) = \tilde{E}(k,\omega)\cdot \tilde{E}^*(k,\omega) = |\tilde{E}(k,\omega)|^2$$

The issue I'm having here is that by definition, the Fourier Transform of a complex signal is:

$$ \tilde{E}(k,\omega) = FT \left[ E(x,t) \right] $$

and

$$ \tilde{E}^* (-k,-\omega) = FT\left[ E^* (x,t) \right] $$

So given the 2D spectral transform ($\tilde{E}(k,\omega)$)  of a complex signal ($E(x,t)$) (say with $n\times n$ discrete frequency bins), how would one compute the spectral intensity that corresponds to the physical intensity?

I can't find this anywhere, and it seems like everyone just uses
$$ \tilde{I}(k,\omega) = \tilde{E}(k,\omega)\cdot \tilde{E}^*(k,\omega) = |\tilde{E}(k,\omega)|^2$$ for all complex signals.

Comment: The Fourier transform of does preserver the "intensity" (energy) this is proven by Persval's theorem. The total signal energy in one space (time) is the same in the other space (frequency). The 2D Fourier transform is giving you the power of each frequency and wavenumber component.